# Recursive file search for designated extension

Tags: java, recursion, smb, smbj

I am using `SMBClient` to connect to my SMB server with Java.

How can I recursively scan my entire SMB share to get a listing of all files with an .mp4 extension?

This is my code that only scans the one designated directory:

```
private void btnFileCountActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    SMBClient client = new SMBClient();
    try (Connection connection = client.connect("192.168.X.XXX")) {
        AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("XXXXXXX@hotmail.com", "XXXXXX".toCharArray(), "Mastafin");
        Session session = connection.authenticate(ac);

        try (DiskShare share = (DiskShare) session.connectShare("Folder With Spaces")) {
            for (FileIdBothDirectoryInformation f : share.list("LOTS OF SUBDIRS TO SCAN", "*.mp4")) {
                System.out.println("File : " + f.getFileName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't specify a pattern, so the result includes both files and directories. Call recursively on directories, and filter out non-MP4 files yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some fairly straightforward tweaks to your code to get it to fill an `ArrayList` recursively.  It isn't necessarily the most efficient way of doing this, as it gathers all filenames, and then throws away the ones that don't end with `.mp4`, but it should give you a straightforward place to start building from.

```
private void btnFileCountActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try (SMBClient client = new SMBClient()) {
        try (Connection connection = client.connect(SERVER)) {
            AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(USERNAME, PASSWORD.toCharArray(), WORKGROUP);
            try (Session session = connection.authenticate(ac)) {
                try (DiskShare share = (DiskShare) session.connectShare(SHARE)) {
                    List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
                    listFiles(share, START_DIR, files);
                    files.removeIf(name -> !name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp4"));
                    files.forEach(System.out::println);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

private void listFiles(DiskShare share, String path, Collection<String> files) {
    List<String> dirs = new ArrayList<>();
    String extPath = path.isEmpty() ? path : path + "\\";
    for (FileIdBothDirectoryInformation f : share.list(path)) {
        if ((f.getFileAttributes() & FileAttributes.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY.getValue()) != 0) {
            if (!isSpecialDir(f.getFileName())) {
                dirs.add(f.getFileName());
            }
        } else {
            files.add(extPath + f.getFileName());
        }
    }
    dirs.forEach(dir -> listFiles(share, extPath + dir, files));
}

private static boolean isSpecialDir(String fileName) {
    return fileName.equals(".") || fileName.equals("..");
}
```